# When the real answer may only be in links within comments below the answer, what to do or say?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, comments, answers

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38069/12102) to *What radio frequencies were used by the Soviet space program circa 1961? (“Lost Cosmonaut” recording)* contains a lot of relevant perspective, and is authored by a user who **regularly posts excellent answers** filled with valuable information, often translated by the author from original sources in Russian.

However in the case of this particular answer, I've been trying to encourage the author to include more of the information that seems likely in the links offered in several comments back into the original answer post.

Asking *What radio frequencies...Soviet space program circa 1961?* I'm trying to get a handle on just that, what radio frequencies were used circa 1961 for voice communication between a crewed spacecraft and the ground.

**Question:** Am I overreacting here, or are my requests in comments to put the answer within the answer post reasonable? When the real answer may only be in links within comments below the answer, what to do or say?

Comment: edit the answer

Comment: @JCRM I don't know what edits to make

Comment: @uhoh In that case, I would leave a comment saying that information critical to answering the question needs to be edited into the answer itself and not left only in the comments. Then flag the post for moderator attention.

Comment: @called2voyage okay I thought these ([1](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38060/what-radio-frequencies-were-used-by-the-soviet-space-program-circa-1961-lost/38069#comment121504_38069), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38060/what-radio-frequencies-were-used-by-the-soviet-space-program-circa-1961-lost/38069#comment121506_38069)) were sufficient. A.Rumlin often does a great job of answering and I was hoping leaving a link to this question there would help open a discussion to understand what's happening. I'll add a flag and one more comment.

Comment: @uhoh Looks good, thanks

Comment: "In order to ask a question you must already know most of the answer." Ask a Foolish Question, (Robert Sheckley)¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

JCRM is correct that in many cases it is possible to edit the information into the answer for the user, but in this case the user has engaged in a pattern of omitting critical information from the answer and then adding it to the comments section with multiple comments. **This behavior is discouraged.**

If you see some one off instances of this, you can flag the comments. If you notice a pattern of behavior, you can flag one of the answers with a custom comment describing this pattern to the moderators.